# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString') Xunit test

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core-webapi, xunit, xunit.net, webapi

I am trying to write unit test by Xunit:

```
  public class UserTest
{

    private readonly TestServer _server;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public UserTest()
    {
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder().UseStartup<Startup>());
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task GetAllUserTest()
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("Get"), "/Api/Users");

        var response =await _client.SendAsync(request);

        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

***request*** validation is in my Solution. 
After the test runs, the test fails and message error is:

> **Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'connectionString')**

If I run api, it runs smoothly and has no CONNECTION problem.

**startup.cs:**

```
 services.AddDbContext<BlogProjectContext>(option =>
        option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("BlogProjectConnection"))
        );
```

**appsetings.json:**

```
    {
  "AppSettings": {
    "Secret": "This is the secret key and its very important"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "BlogProjectConnection": "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=BlogProject_DB;Integrated Security=True"

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume your unit tests are in a different project to your API?  Your unit test projects run in a different directory to your API, so they can't 'see' the `appsettings.json` file that your API can, causing you to see this error.

You really don't want your *unit* tests to be issuing real HTTP requests though.  The remedy to this is to [mock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the `HttpClient`.  [Here](https://gingter.org/2018/07/26/how-to-mock-httpclient-in-your-net-c-unit-tests/)'s a useful blog post on mocking `HttpClient`.

Comment: In your link, this code
  var subjectUnderTest = new MyTestClass (httpClient);

What does MyTestClass mean?